# SSIS Package run Manually but throw error with SQL JOB , ERROR : Opening a rowset for "Open_SR" failed. Check that the object exists in the database

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-agent-job, sql-agent

Runs fine manually, throws an error when executing via SQL job.

> Error: Opening a rowset for "Open_SR" failed. Check that the object exists in the database

Comment: Is it executing as the same user as under a SQL Job? Check on the SQL Agent log. Usually not, and that user probably doesn't have access.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a proxy account *(run SQL job with the same credentials use to run manually)*, you can follow one of these links for a step-by-step asnwer.

- [Running a SSIS Package from SQL Server Agent Using a Proxy Account](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2163/running-a-ssis-package-from-sql-server-agent-using-a-proxy-account/)
- [Create a SQL Server Agent Proxy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/create-a-sql-server-agent-proxy)